# Converting from a virtual address space to a physical address spae

Tags: tlb, virtual-address-space

This topic has been somewhat covered in other posts, but in my example I need to find more than what is shown on the other examples, and I struggle to clearly understand what exactly is going on.

Suppose I have the following system properties (and worked example I know the solutions to, but do not understand clearly):

[image]

**And suppose I want to translate the virtual address `0x0712` to a physical address:**

I would first convert `0x0712` to binary: `000011100010010` (knowing the VA is 15-bit wide)

I know the page size is 128 bytes, so `log2(128) = 7`, which is my offset bits.

**I then need to answer the following:**

What is the Virtual Page Number?

What is the TLB index?

What is the TLB tag?

Was it a TLB hit or miss?

Was there a Page fault?

What is the Physical Page Number?

*How do I go about answering these? I know the VPN can be shown as E (or 0E), which makes sense as the 15-bit virtual address minus the offset bits (7) would leave: `00001110 = E`. I also understand why there is no PPN, as there is no match for VPN `0E` in the page table.*

*My guess would be the page fault is Y, exactly because there is no match to the VPN `0E` in the page table? However, I come to this using just intuition.*

**But I dont understand the remaining parts, and how I answer these? Again I know the solutions as:**

What is the Virtual Page Number? = 0E

What is the TLB index? = 2

What is the TLB tag? = 03

Was it a TLB hit or miss? = M

Was there a Page fault? = Y

What is the Physical Page Number? none

But I cant seem to grasp how they arrive at those answers from the worked example above. I've tried to read up on different posts in here, but I fail to spot anyone covering how to find the TLB index and tags properly, and in that case how to see whether is was a TLB hit/miss and if a Page fault happened.

Can anyone explain these concepts to me?

**EDIT:** I found the solution elsewhere, I posted it as a comment below to showcase the worked example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My examining more examples toturials I stumbled upon a solution that made sense to me. In the case from above I have the following:

**What is the Virtual Page Number?**
Virtual address: `0x0712` which maps to binary address: `000011100010010`

I know the offset bits are found by `log2(128) = 7 bits` which leaves the remaining 8-bits for the actual Virtual Address.

**What is the TLB index?**
As I have 4 sets in the TLB, I have 2 index bits (2^k = 4, for k = 2 which is the actual number of index bits needed to cover all 4 sets in the TLB-cache) and thus I can read the TLB index from the 2 least significant bits of the Virtual Address: `10` = `2`.

**What is the TLB tag?**
The TLB tag, is the remaining 8-2 = 6-bits of the Virtual Address, in this case `000011` = `03`.

**Was it a TLB hit or miss?**
To check if I have a TLB hit, I check the TLB table, lookup in set `2` (which was the TLB index) and see if there is a match to the tag `03` (which was the TLB tag). In this case I have no match, and thus there is a TLB MISS.

**Was there a Page fault?**
As the TLB-cache did not provide an answer, I need to lookup the translation from the Virtual Address using the page table instead. So I check the table for a VPN match of `0E`, which there is not, and thus I have a Page Fault. In case I actually found a match, I would need to check the valid bit is `1`, as it indicates if the data is loaded into the page table.

**What is the Physical Page Number?**
As there was no match in the TLB-cache translation, or the actual page table for the Virtual Address `0E`, there is no PPN matching.